# Как сделать яндекс метку произвольного цвета, с фотографией внутри? (YANDEX MAPS API)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Хотел бы сделать метку произвольного цвета, с фотографией внутри, так, чтобы цвет круглой рамки можно было задавать в свойствах placemark и фотографию тоже там же. Возможно ли это сделать стандартными свойствами API или нужно самому допиливать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В песочнице JS API есть [пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage) реализации кастомной метки.

Comment: да, вроде она кастомная, то кастомная, но как ее кастомизировать непонятно, либо применяешь  //iconLayout: 'default#image', iconImageHref: '/mini.jpg', чтобы подгрузить свое изображение, либо пользуешься ограниченным набором preset-меток, как например, preset: 'islands#circleIcon', А есть ли способ задать метке CSS-класс, чтобы к примеру скруглить края и задать цвет и толщину границе?

Comment: Кажется понял, надо для такого случая использовать кастомный макет и указывать его в свойстве iconContentLayout: